# QTabWidget with sticky tabs

Tags: qt, qtabwidget

In a Python script, I'm creating a stack of tabbed widgets via `QTabWidget`. I would like one tab to be sticky; more precisely, regardless of how many widgets are created, I would like the tab associated with the initial widget to remain visible at all times. Is this possible?

Clarification: If enough tabs are created, a scroll bar appears, and older tabs will slide off to the left and be accessible only via scrolling.  I would like to have one special tab remain visible at all times, regardless of the scroll bar position.

Comment: Just subclass QTabWidget and block any delete for the first tab.

Comment: What do you mean with "remain visible"? Is it a problem of deleting or that the tabbar contains too many entries so that the scrollbar appears and the first tab should always be accesible directly?

Comment: I've already subclassed and am preventing deletion of specific tabs, but still haven't found a way to prevent the "main" tab from scrolling off the edge of the window.